# Mode SQL: Dynamic Date Parameters

Tags: sql, parameters, amazon-redshift, liquid, mode

I am trying to create a parameter using Mode SQL that will be dynamic to the first and last date of the current month as start and end dates. I put my code below that I know doesn't work. You have to use Liquid SQL (https://mode.com/help/articles/parameters/#dynamic-options-list) that I'm not very familiar with.

```
{% form %}

start_date:
  type: date
  default: date_add(month, -1, date_trunc(month, current_date))
 
end_date:
  type: date
  default: LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE,YYYY-MM-DD))

{% endform %}
```

Comment: Please explain why it doesn't work. Do you get an error or incorrect values? Maybe you meant to post this link: https://mode.com/help/articles/parameters/#date

Comment: In fact this code sample, on that exact same page, looks more like what you're after. https://mode.com/help/articles/parameters/#default-to-a-calculated-date

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that does show how to add / subtrack days but not look at the last day / first day in a given month. I've tried a few versions using the liquid code and haven't been able to to a successful run. The parameter SQL is running fine but the SQL running my actual table that uses the parameter gets an error message

Comment: And the error message is? Please add it to the question

Comment: If you are using native sql please add a tag for the RDBMS. Oracle?

Comment: No error message but it returns no results

Comment: I did tag the native SQL with Liquid. It's Amazon Redshift through mode but you have to use Liquid for the parameters.

Comment: If you want to attack it with the native SQL approach, I suggest you open a redshift query tool and try some direct queries to confirm the syntax is doing what you think.

Comment: You could also use this to inspect the actual query that is being submitted  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/performance-metrics-query-history.html

Comment: It's not using redshift sql - that's why I didn't put that in my question. It's use mode liquid SQL.

Comment: Looking at that help page it seems you can also use mode inspect the output of your template I.e.the SQL query. So you have a number of ways to do further investigation.

Comment: You must be connecting to some type of database server. That is neither a mode nor a liquid server because they aren’t db servers.

Comment: It's a redshift server but the sql itself for parameters is liquid which is unique to mode from what i understand

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but it doesn't seem like you know the answer - which is totally reasonable - but I think maybe if someone else is able to help that would be more beneficial to me.

Comment: That’s OK. We could walk through this and sort it out or you can wait for someone else who has actually used this tool before. All I can say is you are getting liquid and native sql mixed up here. If you are going to use native SQL then you should troubleshoot in a SQL tool. All this stuff is the same you just have to break the problem down.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hacky way to do it. Works well for the 1st of the month, not so well for the end, since month ends change dates.

```
{% form %}

start_date:
  type: date
  default: {{ 'now' | date: '%s' | date: '%Y-%m-01' }}
  description: Only display data after this date.
  
end_date:
  type: date
  default: {{ 'now' | date: '%s' | date: '%Y-%m-30' }}
  description: Only display data before this date.

{% endform %}
```